# How to select columns from a dataframe whose names are contained in another series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a series `A` that looks like:

```
data = {'Animal':['a.Bear', 'b.Elephant', '123.Giraffe', 'Kangaroo']}
A = pd.DataFrame(data)

    Animal
0   a.Bear
1   b.Elephant
2   123.Giraffe
3   Kangaroo
```

And a dataframe `df` like:

```
column_names = ['Lion', 'Tiger', 'Bear', 'Elephant', 'Giraffe', 'Kangaroo', 'Rhino', 'Cat', 'Dog']
data = {animal: [random.random() for _ in range(10)] for animal in column_names}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Lion     Tiger      Bear  Elephant   Giraffe  Kangaroo     Rhino  \
0  0.435419  0.139088  0.799243  0.095464  0.252427  0.300750  0.537184   
1  0.536742  0.798354  0.359454  0.962717  0.900115  0.192034  0.255388   
2  0.400937  0.999050  0.464974  0.082873  0.807442  0.152231  0.888681   
3  0.962247  0.585496  0.826572  0.964859  0.061535  0.661318  0.626811   
4  0.315054  0.241821  0.183458  0.767684  0.932423  0.605995  0.121704   
5  0.975635  0.321856  0.640700  0.269786  0.603920  0.451022  0.202050   
6  0.281994  0.790526  0.074202  0.318642  0.825572  0.006433  0.376935   
7  0.002314  0.599871  0.883832  0.838671  0.193689  0.983202  0.365913   
8  0.488496  0.226901  0.318186  0.527369  0.722069  0.152814  0.181855   
9  0.059592  0.483801  0.419581  0.378362  0.064484  0.263958  0.183479   

        Cat       Dog  
0  0.457674  0.930943  
1  0.171235  0.465397  
2  0.230023  0.732982  
3  0.094517  0.373322  
4  0.885030  0.852047  
5  0.759202  0.521539  
6  0.683882  0.520186  
7  0.635325  0.832302  
8  0.950867  0.395677  
9  0.929706  0.858686
```

I want to select only the columns from `df` whose names are contained in the series `A`.

I tried:

```
df.loc[:,A['Animal].str.contains(df.columns)]
```

But I get error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Index'
```

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.map(lambda x: x in ' '.join(A['Animal']))]
```

output [truncated to 4 elements per series]:

```
    Bear        Elephant    Giraffe     Kangaroo
0   0.794328    0.112836    0.357502    0.156082
1   0.840482    0.025965    0.600463    0.408251
2   0.319205    0.239732    0.890557    0.589371
3   0.616569    0.495843    0.244707    0.748728
```

---

**Intermediate**

1.

```
' '.join(A['Animal'])
```

:

```
'a.Bear b.Elephant 123.Giraffe Kangaroo'
```

2. 

```
df.columns.map(lambda x: x in ' '.join(A['Animal']))
```

:

```
Index([False, False, True, True, True, True, False, False, False], dtype='bool')
```

Comment: is the ```.join``` part there making one big string  with spaces between the names?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to preprocess the Series and then select the array:

```py
df.loc[:, A.Animal.str.split('.').str[-1]]
       Bear  Elephant   Giraffe  Kangaroo
0  0.700352  0.205612  0.102616  0.944342
1  0.890737  0.820959  0.651497  0.479565
2  0.699564  0.531335  0.872938  0.091374
3  0.330110  0.106390  0.612813  0.023788
4  0.438814  0.673884  0.332209  0.858403
5  0.275314  0.225742  0.274267  0.019163
6  0.382985  0.269667  0.412339  0.248712
7  0.803773  0.580038  0.634080  0.859197
8  0.000672  0.231498  0.454456  0.035016
9  0.072687  0.342957  0.300143  0.052512
```

The solution above makes some assumptions about the splitter. A more generic approach would be to use a list comprehension:

```py
filters = [word for word in df 
           for wording in A.Animal.array 
           if word in wording]
df.loc[:, filters]

       Bear  Elephant   Giraffe  Kangaroo
0  0.700352  0.205612  0.102616  0.944342
1  0.890737  0.820959  0.651497  0.479565
2  0.699564  0.531335  0.872938  0.091374
3  0.330110  0.106390  0.612813  0.023788
4  0.438814  0.673884  0.332209  0.858403
5  0.275314  0.225742  0.274267  0.019163
6  0.382985  0.269667  0.412339  0.248712
7  0.803773  0.580038  0.634080  0.859197
8  0.000672  0.231498  0.454456  0.035016
9  0.072687  0.342957  0.300143  0.052512
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use a regex for that:

```
import re

# craft a regex from existing columns
target = '|'.join(map(re.escape, sorted(df.columns, key=len, reverse=True)))
# 'Elephant|Kangaroo|Giraffe|Tiger|Rhino|Lion|Bear|Cat|Dog'

# extract the names
keep = A['Animal'].str.extract(f'({target})', expand=False)

# slice columns in original order
out = df[df.columns.intersection(keep)]
```

*If you only want to match full words (e.g. `Cat` shouldn't match `Catfish`), use `fr'\b({target})\b` in `extract`.*

If you have thousands of terms to search, you can greatly improve efficiency by using a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

With [`retrie`](https://github.com/ddelange/retrie):

```
# pip install retrie
from retrie.trie import Trie

t = Trie()
t.add(*df)

keep = A['Animal'].str.extract(f'({t.pattern()})', expand=False)
out = df[df.columns.intersection(keep)]
```

Or with [`trieregex`](https://github.com/ermanh/trieregex):

```
# pip install trieregex
from trieregex import TrieRegEx as TRE

keep = A['Animal'].str.extract(f'({TRE(*df).regex()})', expand=False)
out = df[df.columns.intersection(keep)]
```

Output:

```
       Bear  Elephant   Giraffe  Kangaroo
0  0.586369  0.150831  0.016725  0.204938
1  0.941386  0.098238  0.769691  0.117735
2  0.985639  0.528000  0.076075  0.122066
...
```

Comment: I get an error from the first line ```TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable```

Comment: @Mitch I suspect you have shadowed a python function. Have you used `map` or `sorted` as a variable name? Try in a clean interpreter or first run `del map ; del sorted`

Comment: Did not profile this example, but for very simple problems using re is performance whise less atractive.

Comment: @deponovo well, I would expected the opposite, especially if you pre-process the regex with a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) structure (not done here). It's also more flexible IMO.

Comment: I added an example

Comment: Flexible definitely. If I would expect wild (pun) input , then I would definitely go for the re. I timed the different options from the answers available at the time of writing: yours with "simple" re 217us (very good), sammywemmy's v1 362us, sammywemmy's v2 267us, and Panda Kim's 170us.